# GTK: Resizing widgets contained in a textview

Tags: resize, widget, gtk, gtktextview

I have a `Gtk.TextView` control, and I'm inserting child widgets into it.  I'd like to be able to have the children resize to fit the width of the TextView when the form is resized.  Is there a built-in way to do this?  If not, can anyone suggest a good way of writing my own?

Comment: Fascinating; I wish I remembered why I wanted to do this.  It must have been an interesting project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [gtk_text_view_get_window() method](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/GtkTextView.html#gtk-text-view-get-window) to get the width of the Gtk.TextView. With this number you can resize your child-widget accordingly. If you want to resize the child-widget automatically when the Gtk.TextView resizes, you can use [the signal check-resize](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/GtkContainer.html#GtkContainer-check-resize), to do the resizing.